# Light emitting material in Eevee doesn't cast light on surfaces?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, emission

Bit of  noob, so forgive me in advance.

Working in Eevee in 2.81, I can't get an emission shaded material to cast light onto a surface. I've got bloom enabled, and the emitting surface illuminates plenty of bloom effect, but the material doesn't cast light onto anything else. my other surfaces catch illumination from other lights just fine.

I'm just using an emission shader node and material output - that's all.

I'm used to building light sources out of objects in Cycles - what am I missing?

Comment: See if enabling screen space reflections under Eevee settings helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure emission doesn't work (yet?!?) in Eevee, the object looks bright & it'll effect bloom but it won't light anything up...